# How does Numpy deal with memory allocation when passed as arguments or returned?

Tags: python, numpy, memory-management

#### SCENARIO 1

Considering the code below as ran in IDLE and Python3:

```py
np.ones((1000,1000,1000), dtype=np.float64)

def func1(b):
    b = np.ones((1000,1000,1000), dtype=np.float32)

def func2(b):
    b = np.ones((1000,1000,1000), dtype=np.float32)
    return b
```

Calling `func1(a)` results in a brief memory spike which is immediately released by garbage collector, however calling `func2(a)` will immediately spike memory and remain there (until `gc.collect()` is explicitly called), even though the return value wasn't assigned to any variable. I have no other references to that value available anywhere else.

[image]

#### SCENARIO 2:

Making this even simpler:

```py
def func1():
    b = np.ones((1000,1000,1000), dtype=np.float32)

def func2():
    b = np.ones((1000,1000,1000), dtype=np.float32)
    return b

def func3():
    return np.ones((1000,1000,1000), dtype=np.float32)
```

Then calling `func1()` is the same as in the previous scenario, spiking the memory and immediately releasing it. Calling both `func2()` and `func3()` **no memory is allocated at all**, which is the opposite to the first scenario.

What is happening under the hood to explain this memory allocation behavior? How does the `return` statement affect the allocation?

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned you are running in IDLE.

The interactive session will save a reference to the last returned value in the `_` variable, which means your numpy array has a reference count preventing it from being collected immediately. Deleting `builtins._` should free the memory.

See [`sys.displayhook`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook) docs for more info.

Comment: Thanks, will check that in a second, that would explain the first bit of the question.

Still this doesn't seem to explain why in the second scenario ```func1()``` allocates something and then releases while ```func2()``` and ```func3()``` don't seem to allocate anything at all. They both have return statement so I wonder how that relates to this behaviour. Any ideas?

Comment: I should have probably made it clearer that when I said 'nothing happens' in the second scenario, it appeared that no memory was allocated at all. Edited the original post now to explain this.

Comment: Calling `func3()` will overwrite again the `_` reference, freeing memory as the previous object is deleted but then immediately re-using the same amount of memory for the new object, with a net effect appearing as no change.